# User policy with git and apache

Tags: apache-2.2, git, user-management

I want to setup git repository on my server so it is accessible from my webserver (read and write with redmine). I want to be able to create repository with my user (*toto*) in SSH.

Currently I set up the following:

- I have created a /var/redmine/repositories (owned by *toto*)
- I create repo in this folder and then change ownership to *www-data*

Currently the repositories are github clone but I would like in the future host my own repositories on the server.

In this context I plan to use a proper *git* user and include *www-data* user in *git* group.

Does it seems correct?

Answer (score 0):

So, I guess you will be using your `git` user to create the repositories, instead of `toto`?

You may be facing a problem if you choose this path, depending on your [umask](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/understanding-linux-unix-umask-value-usage.html). Try issuing this commands:

```
git@host$ mkdir tata.git
git@host$ ls -ld tata
```

If your `umask` is `002`, this will show this:

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 git git 4096 Nov 11 13:50 tata.git
```

And this is fine. However, if your `umask` is `022` - which is the case in most distributions, then you will get this:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 git git 4096 Nov 11 13:50 tata.git
```

You see that here, the members of group `git` only have `r-x` permission on the folder - no write permissions at all. So even if you make `www-data` part of group `git`, the webserver won't have write permissions on that repository.

The solution, as stated in the above link, is to set your `umask` to `002` in the appropriate file, which in most cases, will be your /home/git/.profile, like this:

```
umask 002
```